# Waiting for thread pool to idle before forking

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php, threadpool

I use docker for building a local environment of Laravel container. When I exec `composer install` in Laravel container, I've got the following messages and stop progression.

```
E1204 08:05:18.874860507      77 thread_pool.cc:253]                   Waiting for thread pool to idle before forking
```

I'm quite not sure about this message but I guess that processes are working a lot and might be occupied in my mac device. So I killed some process but nothing changed.
Then, I reboot my PC, but same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587256/php-warning-module-imagick-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages - include the code/error message as text instead, to ease searchability and accessibility.

Comment: Apart from the duplicate, what is your question? And what @janw wrote, please [edit] your question and write out (at least once) the message you're concerned about. Just make everything clear in text form, otherwise questions don't work well on Stackoverflow. See as well [help].

Comment: If there is a gRPC dependency on the project, you may take a look at the [bug/issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/31772). Workaround: according to the [PR](https://github.com/colopl/laravel-spanner/pull/55/files) on colopl/laravel-spanner, you can stick gRPC version on 1.49.0.

Comment: This problem is occurred by gRPC dependency and I fix the version 1.49.0 and it works.